# Why does Paul not request removing those teaching a serious theological error in 1 Cor. 15:12?

Tags: paul, pauline-epistles, biblical-application

In 1 Cor. 15:12 Paul writes:

> Now if Christ is proclaimed as raised from the dead, how can some of you say that there is no resurrection of the dead? (ESV)

But Paul gives no disciplinary action to those teaching this error, in contrast to discipline for the moral issue in 1 Cor. 5:1-2.

> It is actually reported that there is sexual immorality among you, and of a kind that is not tolerated even among pagans, for a man has his father’s wife.  And you are arrogant! Ought you not rather to mourn? Let him who has done this be removed from among you.
> (ESV)

What is the implication of this with handing serious theological error?

Comment: The implication is one who questions the resurrection may not be a believer. If so, the church can not "remove" a person who is not a true member. In that case, Paul says the church is to give proper instruction and to avoid them if they persist (see verse 15:33-34).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question perfectly illustrates the important difference between theological differences and moral differences.

- Moral lapses should be dealt with by the local congregation as in 1 Cor 5 and Matt 18:15-17.
- Theological differences cannot and should not be punished because that would be deny freedom of religion.  Such intolerance led to the excesses of the medieval period where people were tortured or killed for thinking differently from some enforced orthodoxy.

The first is a moral failure that leads to aberrant outward behavior and the need to protect the victims; the second is a difference in thought patterns which cannot be judged except by God.

This is not to suggest that serious theological differences should not be faced, discussed and dealt with - as Paul was doing in 1 Cor 15:12ff; but one cannot be punished for holding a sincere opinion.

The big problem for serious theological differences is usually one of two things:

- it diminishes Christ and His ministry and position somehow
- it destroyed unity of the congregation/church (not that we seek uniformity!) but without unity, almost nothing can be accomplished.

Paul dealt with theological differences by providing good teaching, as he did in most of his letters (most were written to correct theological errors of some sort).  However, he never advocated punishment for heterodox views.

**APPENDIX - Further Note**

We must tread very carefully in this area of theological difference.  Some behave as if correct theology is required to be saved.  Such forget that we are saved by Christ alone and faith in Christ alone!  If correct and/or correct understanding of theology is required to be saved, no one will be saved.

We all understand imperfectly to some extent.  See 1 Cor 13:12.

Comment: Does this agree with Galatians 1:8?

Comment: @RevelationLad - I think Paul in Gal 1:8 is stating a simple fact - false doctrine leads to a lack of trust in Christ (always) and ends (finally) with the person being unable to trust/have faith in Christ.  That is the only way to be saved because we cannot save ourselves as per Heb 11:6.

Comment: I think cursing anyone who preaches a different Gospel is contrary to tolerating religious freedom as you present it here.

Comment: @RevelationLad - then the problem becomes, who is going to act as the "Correct Gospel Police"?

Comment: Again in Gal. 1:8-9, Paul wasn't asking for any disciplinary action by the churches in Galatia.

Comment: In contrast to Gal. 1:8-9 see https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/how-should-we-contextualize-pauls-jesus-is-accursed-in-i-co-123/32980#32980

Comment: @PerryWebb - many thanks - a predictably excellent answer from you and a good companion answer to this question too.

Comment: @PerryWebb Nor was he saying to ignore it. In Galatia the issue is clearly one of **outsiders** attempting to bring in false teaching. The difference is the church cannot, nor should it try to discipline **outsiders**. This is the **type** of religious freedom Dottard's answer addresses. The Church has no business imposing or even considering disciple on a non-believer. The proper response is correct teaching. OTOH, if a **believer** commits the type of sin in Chapter 5, the church needs to take corrective action precisely because they are a member.

Comment: @PerryWebb   you say Paul wasn't asking for any disciplinary action   in Gal 1.8 but it is possible that he was indeed doing when he said that those who teach "another gospel" should be anathema. This refers to the Judaizers, not to those who denied the resurrection of the dead. I argue in my answer that a. the Galatian heresy was fundamental to Paul and b. his authority in Corinth was not firmly established.

Comment: Anathema is handing the discipline over to God rather than asking the churches in Galatia to do the discipline.

Comment: @PerryWebb - did you realize that this apparently simple question would generate so much debate?

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**
As Dottard shows in [this answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/85847/why-does-paul-not-request-removing-those-teaching-a-serious-theological-error-in/85848#85848), the two situations can be treated differently on the basis of moral lapses versus theological differences. This approach ignores a significant difference between the two situations. The moral issue involves a person who is unquestionably a believer, and so is unquestionably a member of the Church. On the other hand, disputes about the resurrection raise the issue of whether a person is truly in the Church. Obviously, no action should even be considered if the individual is not a member.

**Paul's Personal Experience**
Consider these experiences Paul describes:

> <sup>13</sup> For you have heard of my former life in Judaism, how I persecuted the church of God violently and tried to destroy it. <sup>14</sup> And I was advancing in Judaism beyond many of my own age among my people, so extremely zealous was I for the traditions of my fathers. (Galatians 1 ESV)

> <sup>22</sup> Are they Hebrews? So am I. Are they Israelites? So am I. Are they offspring of Abraham? So am I. <sup>23</sup> Are they servants of Christ? I am a better one—I am talking like a madman—with far greater labors, far more imprisonments, with countless beatings, and often near death. <sup>24</sup> **Five times I received at the hands of the Jews the forty lashes less one**. (2 Corinthians 11)

Both describe actions which the **assembly** believed were justified on the basis of discipling **members**. Paul willing submits **five times** to being discipled because he still **claims to be a member of that assembly**. For that reason he is subject to be disciplined **by the assembly**. This does not mean the actions were right. It points out what happened to Paul was a consequence of his claim **to be a member** and therefore to be subject to the rules of the assembly.

There are **two considerations** in what happened to Paul:

1. Is the person a member of the assembly? If not, the assembly has no right to take action.
2. If so, how should the assembly address the issue?

**Corinth: Two Different Situations**
These considerations point to a significant difference in Corinth. In the case of the sinner in Chapter 5, the one in the wrong unquestionably **belongs** to the assembly. This situation requires what should **believers** do when **another believer** acts in a way which is unmistakably outside of what is acceptable:

> It is actually reported that there is sexual immorality among you, and of a kind that is **not tolerated even among pagans**... (1 Corinthians 5)

No assembly, Christian, Jewish, or pagan would allow this individual to remain **in the assembly**. In addition to the primary reason, Paul gives a another consideration:

> <sup>33</sup> Do not be deceived: “Bad company ruins good morals.” <sup>34</sup> Wake up from your drunken stupor, as is right, and do not go on sinning. For some have no knowledge of God. I say this to your shame. (1 Corinthians 15)

It should be noted Paul does give instruction on how to respond to the theological error of the resurrection. Those continuing to promote this error are to be avoided.

With respect to the questions about resurrection, the specifics are not clear. Nor is clear who are the "preparators" behind the question. Nevertheless, Paul is well aware **outsiders** denied the resurrection of Jesus Christ. So he gives instruction how to respond as if an **outsider** is denying the resurrection. Obviously expulsion is both impossible and wrong since the assembly should **never** attempt to discipline an **outsider**.

It is possible the issue does not question the resurrection of Jesus. But there is no dispute denying the resurrection was (and still is) a claim of  unbelievers. It is made by those **outside** the assembly.

**Conclusion**
Regardless of the specifics, the denial of the resurrection is the fundamental position of **non-believers**. It is true there might be exceptions, but Paul's instructions are always applicable. The assembly should **not discipline** someone over their disputing the resurrection which is Paul's "litmus test" for membership in the Church:

> <sup>9</sup> because, if you confess with your mouth that Jesus is Lord and believe in your heart that God raised him from the dead, you will be saved. <sup>10</sup> For with the heart one believes and is justified, and with the mouth one confesses and is saved. <sup>11</sup> For the Scripture says, “Everyone who believes in him will not be put to shame.” <sup>12</sup> For there is no distinction between Jew and Greek; for the same Lord is Lord of all, bestowing his riches on all who call on him. <sup>13</sup> For “everyone who calls on the name of the Lord will be saved.”
> (Romans 10)

Unlike the sinner in Chapter 5, the Church responds differently when there is **a question of membership**. Questions over resurrection cut to the heart of what **determines membership** in the assembly. The church should never attempt to take action against someone whose actions bring into question their **status as a member**. Rather, they are to give clear instruction and avoid those who persist in denying the resurrection.

Comment: Really??  Persecution for one's belief's are justified in some situations??

Comment: @Dottard Persecution? Where do I say persecution is ok? Paul never instructs to persecute. He instructed to expel the sinner in Chapter 5 and to stay away from the those doubting the resurrection. If you are speaking of what the Jews did, that is something **they** did to Paul. Paul did not have to submit, as Acts later shows. He **chose** to submit because he saw himself as a member of that assembly. Your religious freedom position dismisses the reality those denying the resurrection are non-believers. The proper response by the assembly is avoidance, as I clearly state.

Comment: You say of Paul and his persecution: "actions which were justified on the basis of membership".

Comment: @Dottard I reworded that to make clear "justify" speaks to the difference between the assembly discipling a member vs an outsider. Which is the situation Paul addresses in Chapter 15. Questions about resurrection call into question whether the person belongs to the church or not. You should give some consideration to what the church should do if someone does not believe Jesus was raised from the dead. In that case the answer is: nothing other than teach correct theology and avoid those who persist. Exactly as Paul states, unlike chapter 5 you cannot discipline an outsider.

Comment: Tread very carefully here - Paul persecuted Jews who were supposed to be members of the Jewish faith and subject to the Jewish assembly. Sometimes there is greater religious freedom outside some churches that within - an appalling irony!

Comment: It was God disciplining Paul on the road to Damascus that was effective, not 50 lashes.

Comment: @PerryWebb You asked why did Paul remove the man in one case and not the other. The answer is straightforward. The man engaged in sexual morality was a believer. As such the church was obligated to respond. Paul's instruction is to remove him. In this case it is appropriate for the **church** to act, because he belongs to the church. OTOH, anyone who denies the resurrection is not a believer. Therefore, they are not a member of the church and the church cannot remove them. Rather, they are to give proper instruction and avoid if they persist. What is so difficult?

Comment: @Dottard Please see my comment to Perry. The issue is not about religious freedom as you insist. The issue is how does the church respond to a **non-believer**. To put the issue in your terms, how does the church respond to someone who exercises their religious freedom to reject the resurrection? Obviously the church cannot remove someone who is not a believer, that is why Paul did not give instruction to remove them. Instead, correct response to rejecting the resurrection is to continue to give proper instruction and then to avoid.

Comment: @Dottard Again to be very clear, the only "discipline" was removal, not beating. I included that to show how any assembly may use the authority to discipline their **members**. Obviously, non members cannot be disciplined because they do not belong! Paul did not instruct removal because the heart of that issue is whether or not the person(s) even belongs to the church. Hence, the churches only action is to give correct instruction and avoid bad company. What is so difficult?

Answer (score 0):

First a note of clarification, Paul is speaking here of the resurrection of the dead generally, not the resurrection of Jesus per se. Thus he argues in this next verse: "if there is no resurrection of the dead, not even Christ has been raised." If it were the resurrection of Jesus itself that had been denied, Paul would be more likely to take a disciplinary stance. To the Galatians he urged drastic action when the Gospel itself was at stake: “If we, or an angel from Heaven, should preach to you a gospel contrary to what we have preached to you, he is to be anathema!" (Gal. 1:8)

Let's remember that Paul wrote at a time when his own leadership was not firmly established at Corinth.

> Each one of you is saying, “I am of Paul,” and “I of Apollos,” and “I
> of Cephas,” and “I of Christ.” (1 Cor. 12)

This must have been one reason that Paul accepted some theological divergence. Even as an apostle his authority did not go unchallenged. In Rom 16, he cautioned against "those who cause dissension." He did not want fall into that category himself.

Later generations would draw bright lines between acceptable and "heretical" dissenting doctrines. This is one of the main reasons for the development of formal creeds. Regarding this particular example, the creedal formula adopted at Nicaea includes the following:

> we look
> for the resurrection of the dead and the life of the world to come.

Those who did not accept this doctrine henceforth were not qualified to calls themselves Christians, at least in the "orthodox" churches.

**In addition to the fact that this was a theological error rather than a moral one, a likely reason that Paul did not discipline those who denied the resurrection of the dead is that his teaching on the matter - as well as his own authority at Corinth- was not yet well established. Virtually everyone knew that moral errors such as incest and adultery were unacceptable. But a significant part of the Corinthian congregation apparently did not believe in the resurrection of the dead. For that reason, Paul needed to use persuasion rather than discipline. Otherwise he himself might fall into the category of "those who cause dissention" whom he denounced in Rom. 16.**

Answer (score 0):

It might have been a small level of emerging ignorance among some, which could've been easily corrected. There is no need to excommunicate someone over the first knowledge of the error; the strength and complete context of the theological error has not been given, so it is speculative to judge the case. Nothing suggests that Paul is treating this lightly. He rebuked the denial of general resurrection by connecting it with Christ's resurrection, implying that it is a fundamental belief. It may be more unacceptable than the Sadducees' rejection of the resurrection, prior to Christ's resurrection, for the Jews.

Sexual sins on the other hand is a severe issue which is assumed to be unrepentant and suggesting a complete disregard to the law of God, hence, it is not surprising to see a direct instruction to throw such a man away from all contacts to protect the church. Compared to this, the ignorance or error about the physical resurrection is not a big deal. It is on the [basis of works](https://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=according%20to%20works&t=NKJV#s=s_primary_0_1) that God will judge man, not by minor errors of faith.

| Luke 9:49-50 NMB |
| --- |
| And John answered and said, Master, we saw a man casting out devils in your name, and we told him not to, because he does not follow with us. And Jesus said to him, Forbid him not. For whoever is not against us, is with us. |