In Ecclesiastes 7:16, does Qoheleth say that it is bad to be very righteous and very wise, or that it is bad to be self-righteous and vainly wise?

Ecclesiastes 7:16 NASB
"Do not be excessively righteous, and do not be overly wise."

Current translations make the passage appear to convey that it is not good to be very righteous and wise, which completely contradicts a number of passages regarding the path to godly perfection and blamelessness by living a life of free of sin and conforming to the image of Christ in the wisdom and righteousness of God through the Holy Spirit.
Could it be that Qoheleth was instead warning us against a show of self-righteousness and vain wisdom, rather than a contradictory warning against becoming very righteous and very wise?

Ecclesiastes 7:16 UBS proposal
“Do not make a show of self-righteousness, and do not overdo
a claim to be wise.”

See the United Bible Societies commentary
Ogden, Graham S. and Zogbo, Lynell. A Handbook on the Book of Ecclesiates. (UBS Helps for Translators). New York: UBS, 1997.

The Holy Spirt knows that human beings are limited and requests them to balance everything, to implement checks and balances in their holiness and wisdom so it does not lead to pride which leads to a fall.

The Hebrew is simple:
אַל־תְּהִ֤י צַדִּיק֙ הַרְבֵּ֔ה וְאַל־תִּתְחַכַּ֖ם יֹותֵ֑ר לָ֖מָּה תִּשֹּׁומֵֽם׃
(Ecc. 7:16, BHS2003)
Literally "Don't be very righteous and smarter; why be desolate.
So, the interpretation depends on the context.
Note the previous verse:

In my own brief span of life, I have seen both these things: sometimes a good man perishes in spite of his goodness, and sometimes a wicked one endures in spite of his wickedness.
(Ecc. 7:15, JPS1985)

The Jewish Publication Society translates it.

So don’t overdo goodness and don’t act the wise man to excess, or you may be dumfounded.
(Ecc. 7:16, JPS1985)

The context is the righteous man dying in spite of his righteousness.  Thus, don't expect righteousness to save your neck.  This context involves the outward display of righteousness.  Under a less than righteous government, there are times when keeping your righteousness as well as what you know to yourself is safer.  Consider what lead to the death of John the Baptist.
Conclusion
What the "very" and "smarter" tends to express in this context is not be be condescending, which has sometimes been called a "holier than thou" complex.  (A New Testament example, see Luke 18:9-14)
References

hitp: impf. תִּתְחַכַּם, נִתְחַכְּמָה: —1. to deal wisely, shrewdly (לְ with) Ex 1:10 Sir 10:26 32/354; —2. to show oneself wise Qoh 7:16. †
--
Koehler, L., Baumgartner, W., Richardson, M. E. J., & Stamm, J. J. (1994–2000). In The Hebrew and Aramaic lexicon of the Old Testament (electronic ed., p. 314). E.J. Brill.


Hithp. Impf. נִתְחַכְּמָה לוֹ Ex 1:10 (E) let us deal wisely (shrewdly) toward it (the people); 2 ms. תִּתְחַכַּם Ec 7:16 make or shew thyself wise.
--
Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). In Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon (p. 314). Clarendon Press.


But that doesn't make sense to me. Why would we need to be a "little wicked" and not overly righteous?

@ Joshua  Are you saying, for example, that North Korean Christians should voluntarily go up to their government and say, "I'm a Christian.  Put me in jail."  Otherwise, they are a little evil?  Are you saying that Christians were a little evil for hiding Jews from Nasi's during World War II.

Not at all. Overly righteous simply means that one fully obeys and followed all of Jesus' commandments.

Overly righteous is an English interpretation and not specifically stated in Hebrew.  The Hebrew could also be interpreted as displaying one's righteousness in a bragging manner.  See Luke 18:9-14.

See added conclusion.

PerryWebb - Isn't there a difference between being "holier than thou" and being discreetly holy to the point of perfection, without being self righteous?

@JoshuaB IMHO in the Christian tradition none of the saints considered themselves as particularly holy or righteous, and any such claims are frown upon as arrogance. Holiness is an unattainable ideal, and not to the person themselves to judge. Let those holy to perfection throw the first stone.

@RogerV. - Under the New Covenant, being righteous under Christ means that we don't throw physical stones at physical adulterers, but we throw spiritual stones at spiritual adulterers. This means that we remove spiritual adulterers out of the Church, that is, spiritual death to those who cheat on their husband Christ by embracing sin without confessing it and remaining pure in the Body of Christ..

https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/85847/why-does-paul-not-request-removing-those-teaching-a-serious-theological-error-in

Ecclesiastes 7:13-18 NIV

13 Consider what God has done: Who can straighten
what he has made crooked?
14 When times are good, be happy;
but when times are bad, consider this:
God has made the one
as well as the other.
Therefore, no one can discover
anything about their future.
15 In this meaningless life of mine I have seen both of these:
the righteous perishing in their righteousness,
and the wicked living long in their wickedness.
16 Do not be overrighteous,
neither be overwise—
why destroy yourself?
17 Do not be overwicked,
and do not be a fool—
why die before your time?
18 It is good to grasp the one
and not let go of the other.
Whoever fears God will avoid all extremes.

It is crucial to understand that whenever something happens, it is because God has allowed it. Ecclesiastes 7:16 warns those who believe they act on behalf of the God's righteousness to right wrongs, without realizing they may be acting against God's will.
"Whoever fears God will avoid all extremes", for "Pride" drives anyone to extremes, forgetting that "Wisdom preserves those who have it" (Ecclesiastes 7:12)
Ecclesiastes 7:8-9 reminds us that "Pride" can make us fools;

8 The end of a matter is better than its beginning,
and patience is better than pride.
9 Do not be quickly provoked in your spirit,
for anger resides in the lap of fools. (NIV)

Therefore the lesson is not about "righteousness", "self-righteousness" or "overly-righteousness", but to remember Paul's teaching in Romans 12:19;

Do not take revenge, my dear friends, but leave room for God’s wrath, for it is written: “It is mine to avenge; I will repay,” says the Lord. (NIV)


That still doesn't explain what it means to not be "too righteous".

@JoshuaB - consider the Book of Job, his friends believed they were righteous, but God rebuked them. When one believes in their righteousness to an extreme, they are deceived by their own pride.

VincentWong - I understand that Job's friends were self-righteous. But do you think that Ecclesiastes 7:16 is about self-righteousness or great genuine righteousness?

@JoshuaB - Eccl 7:13 "Consider what God has done: Who can straighten what he has made crooked?". The term "crooked" represent wickedness, does it mean God is wicked? The narrative might actually carry an ironic twist. 7:18 reminds us "Whoever fears God will avoid all extremes" conveying a clear message. Those who hold God in reverence will refrain from assuming the role of God in judgment over others. Considering the entire context, 7:16 presents a twist.

VincentWong - to judge is to commit a sin. So in a sense, are you confirming that self-righteousness is the picture here?

@JoshuaB - I would emphasize that these individuals are acting without God in mind, rather than debating the righteousness of  their actions. Sometimes we do possess correct knowledge but apply it in the wrong scenario. Therefore the focus should be on God rather than their specific deeds. I hope I make myself clear.

VincentWong - isn't what you describe called self-righteousness?

In Eccl 7, there is a flow of thought that begins in V15 and should not be separated from that which follows:

15 In this meaningless life of mine I have seen both of these:
the righteous perishing in their righteousness, and the wicked living
long in their wickedness.
16 Do not be overrighteous, neither be overwise— why destroy yourself?
17 Do not be overwicked, and do not be a fool— why die before your time?
18 It is good to grasp the one and not let go of the other.
Whoever fears God will avoid all extremes.

Thus, I would "translate" (using Dottard's "extreme paraphrase") V16 as follows:

Do not be so heavenly minded that you are no earthly good

As Ellicott says (about V16) -

(16) Righteous over – much.—The caution is against morbid scrupulosity
and over-rigorism.

The Pulpit commentary is even better:

Verse 16. - Be not righteous over much. The exhortation has been
variously interpreted to warn against too scrupulous observance of
ritual and ceremonial religion, or the mistaken piety which neglects
all mundane affairs, or the Pharisaical spirit which is bitter in
condemning others who fall short of one's own standard. Cox will have
it that the advice signifies that a prudent man will not be very
righteous, since he will gain nothing by it, nor very wicked, as he
will certainly shorten his life by such conduct. But really Koheleth
is condemning the tendency to immoderate asceticism which had begun to
show itself in his day - a rigorous, prejudiced, indiscreet manner of
life and conduct which made piety offensive, and afforded no real aid
to the cause of religion. This arrogant system virtually dictated the
laws by which Providence should be governed, and found fault with
divinely ordered circumstances if they did not coincide with its
professors' preconceived opinions. Such religionism might well be
called being "righteous over much."


What were your thoughts on the UBS commentary?

@JoshuaB - quite reasonable.

So is "self-righteous" an okay translation in this passage??

@JoshuaB - "self-righteous" is a valid interpretation but not an accurate translation.

Dottard - then could it be translated this way to prevent people from coming to a dangerously faulty interpretation?

@JoshuaB - It is always safer to translate only NOT to translate AND interpret.

Dottard - then don't you think that we should translate the passage according to the way that brings out the original interpretation, instead of translating it in such as away that creates confusion and false doctrine?
